# getFriendsTimeline Returning Nothing

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using the [Twitterlibphp](http://github.com/jdp/twitterlibphp/tree/master) for a Twitter project and using the [`getFriendsTimeline()`](http://jdp.github.com/twitterlibphp/doc/twitterlibphp/TwitterBase.html#methodgetFriendsTimeline) method to get my Home timeline. The problem is that with this code:

```
<?php 
    // require the twitter library
    require "scripts/twitter.lib.php";

    // your twitter username and password
    $username = "MyUser";
    $password = "MyPass";

    // initialize the twitter class
    $twitter = new Twitter($username, $password);

    // fetch public timeline in xml format
    $options = array("count" => 20);
    $xml = $twitter->getFriendsTimeline($options);
    //$xml = $twitter->getPublicTimeline();

    $twitter_status = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    foreach($twitter_status->status as $status) {
        foreach($status->user as $user) {
                echo '<li class="tweet"><img src="' . $user->profile_image_url . '" class="twitter_image">';
                echo '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' . $user->name . '">' . $user->name . '</a>: ';
        }
        echo $status->text;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<div class="twitter_posted_at">Posted at: ' . $status->created_at . '</div>';
        echo "</li>";
    }
?>
```

When I tried to `echo $xml` I got this response:

> Basic authentication is not supported

What I'm doing wrong?

Before I tried this code I was using the [`getPublicTimeline()`](http://jdp.github.com/twitterlibphp/doc/twitterlibphp/TwitterBase.html#methodgetPublicTimeline) correctly and without any problems.

*PS: On my source code the* `$username` *and* `$password` *variables are correct and using my credentials*

Answer (score 1):

From a cursory glance of the source code provided, and with little knowledge of Twitterlibphp, it seems as though you're seeing the error you've mentioned because Twitter has recently dropped support for HTTP Basic Auth.

As documented [here](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/oauth/authorize), OAuth is the new authentication standard required of all Twitter applications. For a popular PHP implementation of Twitter OAuth support, see abraham's GitHub project [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth).

Comment: So what I need to change on my code to make it work with OAuth?